# MySQL sugar syntax to create an authenticated, all-privileged user and its database

Tags: mysql, sql

This is how I create an authenticated, all-privileged user and its database in MySQL through the MySQL CLI in Linux (Ubuntu with Bash):

```
cat <<-DBSTACK | mysql -u root -p"${dbrootp}"
    CREATE (OR RE-CREATE IF NEEDED) USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${dbuserp}";
    CREATE (OR RE-CREATE IF NEEDED) DATABASE ${domain};
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO "${domain}"@"localhost";
DBSTACK
```

Is there some sugar syntax, or some high functionality that does all of that in a single line?

(would be better than running 5 lines - 2 for an here-document opener and delimiter, and 3 for MySQL).

Comment: I suggest that it does not matter.  This script is rarely run (certainly not every second).  Spend your time on other scripts.  Meanwhile, the Answers with a bash function and a Stored Proc are "cleaner" ways of doing the task, and get you down to a "single line".

Comment: @RickJames: And, as described in my answer, can be more secure too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no combined syntax per the MySQL docs, presumably because - generally -
 `CREATE USER` and `CREATE DATABASE` are executed once, while `GRANT` is executed more than once.

One way to reduce the syntax overhead is to encapsulate the SQL construction in a shell function. For bash, that might look like:

```
grant_sql() {
    local user pass
    user="${1:?Missing argument #1: MySQL user name}"
    pass="${2:?Missing argument #2: password for MySQL user}"
    cat <<EOSQL
CREATE USER "${user}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${pass}";
CREATE DATABASE ${user};
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${user}.* TO "${user}"@"localhost";
EOSQL
}
```

Then to fire it off like:

```
grant_sql "myUser" "itsPassword" | mysql -uroot -p...
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any in-built command that would perform all of these tasks as one, but you can easily define your own [stored program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-views.html) to do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addNewDomain(domain VARCHAR(32), password VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
  DECLARE db VARCHAR(66) DEFAULT CONCAT('`', REPLACE(domain, '`', '``'), '`');
  DECLARE ac VARCHAR(76) DEFAULT CONCAT(db, '@localhost');

  SET
    @a := CONCAT('CREATE USER ', ac, ' IDENTIFIED BY ', QUOTE(password)),
    @b := CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', db),
    @c := CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ', db, '.* TO ', ac)
  ;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @a; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @b; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @c; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Which you would then invoke with a single `CALL` statement:

```
CALL addNewDomain('foobar', 's3cr3t')
```

One advantage of this approach is that the procedure can be defined by a user with full `CREATE` and `GRANT` permissions, but permission to `EXECUTE` it granted to a user who does not have those permissions—then your shell script can connect to MySQL using the lower-privileged account (that can cause less damage, eg only set up new domains, if compromised).

Note that, in order to issue the `CREATE PROCEDURE` command (which contains `;` characters) you will need to ensure your MySQL client's statement delimiter is set to something other than `;` or else it will split the command into multiple separate statements when sending to the server.  The MySQL CLI does this using the `DELIMITER` statement:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE addNewDomain(domain VARCHAR(32), password VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
  -- etc
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Create the proc as `root` and add `SECURITY INVOKER`.  This prevents a non-privileged user from running the proc.

Comment: @RickJames: The whole point of what I was trying to say, is that if you *don't* do that but rather control access to who runs the proc via granting of the `EXECUTE` permission upon it, you can allow select non-privileged users to run the proc without granting to them wider permissions to use `CREATE` and `GRANT` commands.  This is a lot better than requiring `root` to run the proc, and therefore exposing yourself to a possible root attack in the event that the invoking script is compromised.

Comment: So, perhaps you need to put the proc in a Database, and limit `EXECUTE` permission for that database to select users?  And use `SECURITY DEFINER`?  Please be explicit in you answer about the `SECURITY` setting and the other steps needed.

Comment: @RickJames: In MySQL, all procs are necessarily defined within a database and their default is `SECURITY DEFINER`, so that doesn't need to be stated explicitly.  As regards granting `EXECUTE` for select users, I have already stated that in my answer.